# How to make my environment variable can be edited more than 1 column (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows, environment-variables, windows-8.1, system-restore

When I want to edit an environment variable I only see one column to edit the value. in the user variables and system variables options.[This is the user variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKiKj.jpg)
[And this is system variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWMLf.jpg)

I see some people on YouTube have more than 1 column to edit variables.[Here is the footage I took from youtube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHdbt.jpg)

I want to replace the path with a different value but it can't be more than one value. because of this I lost the value in the path that was previously used.
I have tried to use system restore but apparently I have not activated the system restore :([This my system restore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBC2m.jpg)

So how to make my environment variable edit have more than 1 column?
or is that feature only available on higher versions of Windows?
Thank you :)

Comment: `path1;path2;path3;path4`

Comment: Thanks now I know how to do it :) sorry for the late respond